# I want toreturn to gnome 3.4 from gnome 3.6 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gnome

I installed ubuntu 12.04 and excited to experience Gnome 3.6. So I add repository and upgraded, But I think I have some graphical problem, So I prefer back to Gnome 3.4, I search in google but I can't find a good article ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you added a ppa to install gnome 3.6 it is easy to revert back.

1. Install ppa-purge: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
2. Run `sudo ppa-purge ppa:your_ppa_address_here`

Whatever was upgraded through the ppa will be reverted back to the original version.